# Why did Ethereum opt for Solidity instead of SDKs for popular languages?

Tags: solidity

It seems to me like creating and maintaining a new language would be much harder than creating and maintaining one or a few SDKs.

And judging from what people write about it and the exploit used to rob the DAO they have far to go to make it easy to develop secure applications in Solidity.

Answer (score 4):

SDK stands for Software Development Kit.

Facebook for example provides a PHP SDK and a Javascript SDK for interacting with its API.

Solidity is a programming language. A constrained one at that. It can not do everything, and in the grand scheme of things it is relatively simple.

Solidity source code is compiled to Bytecode which can be executed by the Ethereum Virtual Machine.

An SDK is essentially a simplified interface to more complex code. Someone could make a Solidity SDK if they so wished, but given that Solidity is not that complex there is no clear benefit.

To answer your question, the EVM is limited in what it can 'execute'. Compiling an existing language with extensive features into bytecode that can be executed by such a simple machine is impossible.